# SWT- set height and scroll in Group

Tags: java, swt

How can I set height and scroll for `Group`? `drawWitness` in the below code, returns a shape. It is not completely in the group with the below code. What should I do?

```
composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
Group grpModelProperties = new Group(composite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
grpModelProperties.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
grpModelProperties.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
Label l1 = new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NULL);
new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NONE);
Label l2 = new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NULL);
new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NONE);
Label l3 = new Label(grpModelProperties, SWT.NULL);
l1.setLayoutData(data);
l1.setText("Some Text1");
l2.setLayoutData(data);
l2.setText("Some Text2");
l2.setSize( 470, 400 );

Label line = new Label(composite, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL );
line.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));

scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite( composite, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );
grpModelProperties1 = new Group(scrolledComposite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
grpModelProperties1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
GridData data1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
data1.heightHint = 150;
grpModelProperties1.setLayoutData(data1);
grpModelProperties1.setText("Test Model");
drawWitness(model);
scrolledComposite.addListener( SWT.Resize, event -> {
   int width = scrolledComposite.getClientArea().width;
   scrolledComposite.setMinSize( composite.computeSize( width, SWT.DEFAULT ) );
 } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width and height hints for the layout data of the group:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
data.widthHint = 200;
data.heightHint = 200;
grpModelProperties1.setLayoutData(data);
```

To use `ScrolledComposite` you need something like:

```
ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(composite, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
// You must set a layout on scrolled composite
scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

// Additional inner composite is required
Composite innerComposite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
innerComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Group grpModelProperties1 = new Group(innerComposite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
grpModelProperties1.setLayout(new GridLayout());
grpModelProperties1.setText("Test Model");

GridData data1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
data1.heightHint = 400;
data1.widthHint = 400;
grpModelProperties1.setLayoutData(data1);

scrolledComposite.setContent(innerComposite);
// No need to use a resize listener
scrolledComposite.setMinSize(innerComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Well it works for me using what little code you have shown. Show us something more like an [mcve] so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: That is because I set the size for window. When I change the height to 100, I see it works. How can I set scroll for it?

Comment: You would have to use `ScrolledComposite` for scrolling

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use ScrolledComposite, but I cannot. I edited my question and added my code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also have `drawWitness(model)` which its return type is void but draw a shape. How can I insert it in the `grpModelProperties1`? I added the content of `drawWitness` function.

Comment: Please do not keep adding extra things to your question. Accept this answer and ask a new question.

Comment: I asked another question. Would you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041908/swt-using-void-function-in-the-group

Comment: about this question, this code set scroll outside of the Group. Is it possible to have scroll inner the Group?

Comment: Yes, you would put the scrolled composite inside the group - but again that is a new question,

Comment: I meant that for this question. By the way, I created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072424/put-scroll-inner-the-group.